# How to pass a second vector into the function that is the third argument of sort() function from C++ STL without using global variables?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, c++17, c++14

I want to pass the below function as as the third argument in sort() function from C++ STL.

```cpp
bool fn(int a, int b, vector<int> v1)
{
    if (v1[a]< v1[b]) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I want sort a vector according to the values in another vector.

```cpp
sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(),fn);
```

How do I pass the first vector `v1` to the function `fn` so that the function `fn` can use it to sort the second vector `v2` without the use of global variables?

Comment: use `lambda` and pass second vect there

Comment: Use a capturing lambda (or perhaps a hand-written function object) instead of a regular function.

Comment: If you don't mind can you show how to use it?

Comment: Sidenote: `if(condition) return true; else return false;` can be simplified to `return condition;`

Comment: I tried to write this function `fn` inside `main`  in hopes that it would be in scope but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your comparator has the wrong signature. `std::sort` expects a callable that can be called with 2 elements.

You can use a lambda expression that captures the vector:

```
sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(),[&v1](const auto& a,const auto& b){ return v1[a]< v1[b]; });
```

---

> I tried to write this function `fn` inside `main` in hopes that it would be in scope but that didn't work.

You cannot define functions within functions. You can define a type with `operator()` inside a function, and thats basically what a lambda expression does. The following hand written functor will achieve the same:

```
struct my_comparator {
    std::vector<int>& v1;
    bool operator(size_t a,size_t b) { 
           return v1[a] < v1[b];
    }
};
std::sort(v2.begin(),v2.end(),my_comparator{v2});
```

Comment: it will be good to check if `a >= 0 && a < v1.size() && b >= 0 && b < v1.size()`

Comment: @Raffallo no, that would be rather expensive, because it would be checked for each single comparison. If this needs to be checked it should be checked only once before using the vector for sorting.

Comment: @Raffallo note that `std::sort` requires O(N logN) comparisons, but that check needs to be done at most N-times (N is `v2.size()`)

Comment: @Raffallo A conforming implementation is permitted to do those checks in `std::vector::operator[]`. MSVC does, in a debug build

Comment: good point guys! :)